# Efficiently XOR two images in Flash compile target

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, shader, haxe, pixel-bender

I need to XOR two `BitmapData` objects together.

I'm writing in Haxe, using the `flash.*` libraries and the AS3 compile target.

I've investigated HxSL and PixelBender, and neither one seems to have a bitwise XOR operator, nor do they have any other bitwise operators that could be used to create XOR  (but am I missing something obvious? I'd accept any answer which gives a way to do a bitwise XOR using only the integer/float operators and functions available in HxSL or PixelBlender).

None of the predefined filters or shaders in Flash that I can find seem to be able to do a XOR of two images (but again, am I missing something obvious? Can XOR be done with a combination of other filters).

I can find nothing like a XOR drawmode for drawing things onto other things (but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist! That would work too, if it exists!)

The only way I can find at the moment is a pixel-by-pixel loop over the image, but this takes a couple of seconds per image even on a fast machine, as opposed to filters, which I use for my other image processing operations, which are about a hundred times faster.

Is there *any* faster method?

Comment: Note that I am asking for BITWISE XOR, here: the same thing that's often used to display brush outlines, create XOR masks on Japanese censor bars, is available as a drawing mode in Java, etc.

Comment: How big are the images you're processing and how are you doing the per-pixel XOR at the moment? I've been testing XORing two 4160x1440 images and my ActionScript solution is ~800ms and PixelBlender is ~6700ms.

Comment: I take two seconds for per-pixel XOR of 2.5k x 2.5k pixel image, in AS3 with a loop over the BitmapData. Simplified, showing only the XOR part:

    for (y = 0; y < input.height; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < input.height; y++) {
            var source_argb:Int = input.getPixel32(x, y);
            var crypt_rgb:Int = crypt.getPixel(x, y);
            bmd.setPixel32(x, y, 
                (argb & 0xff000000) /* Preserve alpha */
                | ((source_argb ^ crypt_rgb) & 0x00ffffff) /* Bitwise XOR */
            );
        }
    }

What algorithm are you using to fake a bitwise XOR in PB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Edit:

Playing around with this a bit more I found that removing the conditional and extra Vector access in the loop speeds it up by about 100ms on my machine.

Here's the previous XOR loop:

```
// Original Vector XOR code:
for (var i: int = 0; i < len; i++) {
    // XOR.
    result[i] = vec1[i] ^ vec2[i];

    if (ignoreAlpha) {
        // Force alpha of FF so we can see the result.
        result[i] |= 0xFF000000;
    }
}
```

Here is the updated XOR loop for the Vector solution:

```
if (ignoreAlpha) {
    // Force alpha of FF so we can see the result.
    alphaMask = 0xFF000000;
}

// Fewer Vector accessors makes it quicker:
for (var i: int = 0; i < len; i++) {
    // XOR.
    result[i] = alphaMask | (vec1[i] ^ vec2[i]);
}
```

---

### Answer:

Here are the solutions that I've tested to XOR two images in Flash.

I found that the PixelBender solution is about 6-10 **slower** than doing it in straight ActionScript.

I don't know if it's because I have a slow algorithm or it's just the limits of trying to fake bitwise operations in PixelBender.

**Results:**

- PixelBender: ~6500ms
- BitmapData.getVector(): **~480-500ms**
- BitmapData.getPixel32(): ~1200ms
- BitmapData.getPixels(): ~1200ms

The clear winner is use `BitmapData.getVector()` and then XOR the two streams of pixel data.

---

### 1. PixelBender solution

This is how I implemented the bitwise XOR in PixelBender, based on the formula given on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Mathematical_equivalents

Here is a Gist of the final PBK: https://gist.github.com/Coridyn/67a0ff75afaa0163f673

On my machine running an XOR on two 3200x1400 images this takes about **6500-6700ms**.

I first converted the formula to JavaScript to check that it was correct:

```
// Do it for each RGBA channel.
// Each channel is assumed to be 8bits.
function XOR(x, y){
    var result = 0;
    var bitCount = 8;   // log2(x) + 1
    for (var n = 0; n < bitCount; n++) {
        var pow2 = pow(2, n);

        var x1 = mod(floor(x / pow2), 2);
        var y1 = mod(floor(y / pow2), 2);

        var z1 = mod(x1 + y1, 2);
        result += pow2 * z1;
    }

    console.log('XOR(%s, %s) = %s', x, y, result);
    console.log('%s ^ %s = %s', x, y, (x ^ y));

    return result;
}

// Split out these functions so it's
// easier to convert to PixelBender.
function mod(x, y){
    return x % y;
}

function pow(x, y){
    return Math.pow(x, y);
}

function floor(x){
    return Math.floor(x);
}
```

Confirm that it's correct:

```
// Test the manual XOR is correct.
XOR(255, 85);   // 170
XOR(170, 85);   // 255
XOR(170, 170);  // 0
```

Then I converted the JavaScript to PixelBender by unrolling the loop using a series of macros:

```
// Bitwise algorithm was adapted from the "mathematical equivalents" formula on Wikipedia:
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Mathematical_equivalents

// Macro for 2^n (it needs to be done a lot).
#define POW2(n) pow(2.0, n)

// Slight optimisation for the zeroth case - 2^0 = 1 is redundant so remove it.
#define XOR_i_0(x, y) ( mod( mod(floor(x), 2.0) + mod(floor(y), 2.0), 2.0 ) )
// Calculations for a given "iteration".
#define XOR_i(x, y, i) ( POW2(i) * ( mod( mod(floor(x / POW2(i)), 2.0) + mod(floor(y / POW2(i)), 2.0), 2.0 ) ) )

// Flash doesn't support loops.
// Unroll the loop by defining macros that call the next macro in the sequence.
// Adapted from: http://www.simppa.fi/blog/category/pixelbender/
// http://www.simppa.fi/source/LoopMacros2.pbk
#define XOR_0(x, y) XOR_i_0(x, y)
#define XOR_1(x, y) XOR_i(x, y, 1.0) + XOR_0(x, y)
#define XOR_2(x, y) XOR_i(x, y, 2.0) + XOR_1(x, y)
#define XOR_3(x, y) XOR_i(x, y, 3.0) + XOR_2(x, y)
#define XOR_4(x, y) XOR_i(x, y, 4.0) + XOR_3(x, y)
#define XOR_5(x, y) XOR_i(x, y, 5.0) + XOR_4(x, y)
#define XOR_6(x, y) XOR_i(x, y, 6.0) + XOR_5(x, y)
#define XOR_7(x, y) XOR_i(x, y, 7.0) + XOR_6(x, y)

// Entry point for XOR function.
// This will calculate the XOR the current pixels.
#define XOR(x, y) XOR_7(x, y)

// PixelBender uses floats from 0.0 to 1.0 to represent 0 to 255
// but the bitwise operations above work on ints.
// These macros convert between float and int values.
#define FLOAT_TO_INT(x) float(x) * 255.0
#define INT_TO_FLOAT(x) float(x) / 255.0
```

XOR for each channel of the current pixel in the `evaluatePixel` function:

```
void evaluatePixel()
{
    // Acquire the pixel values from both images at the current location.
    float4 frontPixel = sampleNearest(inputImage, outCoord());
    float4 backPixel = sampleNearest(diffImage, outCoord());

    // Set up the output variable - RGBA.
    pixel4 result = pixel4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    // XOR each channel.
    result.r = INT_TO_FLOAT ( XOR(FLOAT_TO_INT(frontPixel.r), FLOAT_TO_INT(backPixel.r)) );
    result.g = INT_TO_FLOAT ( XOR(FLOAT_TO_INT(frontPixel.g), FLOAT_TO_INT(backPixel.g)) );
    result.b = INT_TO_FLOAT ( XOR(FLOAT_TO_INT(frontPixel.b), FLOAT_TO_INT(backPixel.b)) );

    // Return the result for this pixel.
    dst = result;
}
```

---

### ActionScript Solutions

#### 2. BitmapData.getVector()

I found the fastest solution is to extract a `Vector` of pixels from the two images and perform the XOR in ActionScript.

For the same two 3200x1400 this takes about **480-500ms**.

```
package diff
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.IBitmapDrawable;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;


    /**
     * @author Coridyn
     */
    public class BitDiff
    {

        /**
         * Perform a binary diff between two images.
         * 
         * Return the result as a Vector of uints (as used by BitmapData).
         * 
         * @param   image1
         * @param   image2
         * @param   ignoreAlpha
         * @return
         */
        public static function diffImages(image1: DisplayObject,
                                          image2: DisplayObject,
                                          ignoreAlpha: Boolean = true): Vector.<uint> {

            // For simplicity get the smallest common width and height of the two images
            // to perform the XOR.
            var w: Number = Math.min(image1.width, image2.width);
            var h: Number = Math.min(image1.height, image2.height);
            var rect: Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h);

            var vec1: Vector.<uint> = BitDiff.getVector(image1, rect);
            var vec2: Vector.<uint> = BitDiff.getVector(image2, rect);

            var resultVec: Vector.<uint> = BitDiff.diffVectors(vec1, vec2, ignoreAlpha);
            return resultVec;
        }


        /**
         * Extract a portion of an image as a Vector of uints.
         * 
         * @param   drawable
         * @param   rect
         * @return
         */
        public static function getVector(drawable: DisplayObject, rect: Rectangle): Vector.<uint> {
            var data: BitmapData = BitDiff.getBitmapData(drawable);
            var vec: Vector.<uint> = data.getVector(rect);
            data.dispose();
            return vec;
        }


        /**
         * Perform a binary diff between two streams of pixel data.
         * 
         * If `ignoreAlpha` is false then will not normalise the 
         * alpha to make sure the pixels are opaque.
         * 
         * @param   vec1
         * @param   vec2
         * @param   ignoreAlpha
         * @return
         */
        public static function diffVectors(vec1: Vector.<uint>,
                                           vec2: Vector.<uint>,
                                           ignoreAlpha: Boolean): Vector.<uint> {

            var larger: Vector.<uint> = vec1;
            if (vec1.length < vec2.length) {
                larger = vec2;
            }

            var len: Number = Math.min(vec1.length, vec2.length),
                result: Vector.<uint> = new Vector.<uint>(len, true);

            var alphaMask = 0;
            if (ignoreAlpha) {
                // Force alpha of FF so we can see the result.
                alphaMask = 0xFF000000;
            }

            // Assume same length.
            for (var i: int = 0; i < len; i++) {
                // XOR.
                result[i] = alphaMask | (vec1[i] ^ vec2[i]);
            }

            if (vec1.length != vec2.length) {
                // Splice the remaining items.
                result = result.concat(larger.slice(len));
            }

            return result;
        }

    }

}
```

#### 3. BitmapData.getPixel32()

Your current approach of looping over the BitmapData with `BitmapData.getPixel32()` gave a similar speed of about **1200ms**:

```
for (var y: int = 0; y < h; y++) {
    for (var x: int = 0; x < w; x++) {
        sourcePixel = bd1.getPixel32(x, y);
        resultPixel = sourcePixel ^ bd2.getPixel(x, y);
        result.setPixel32(x, y, resultPixel);
    }
}
```

#### 4. BitmapData.getPixels()

My final test was to try iterating over two `ByteArray`s of pixel data (very similar to the `Vector` solution above). This implementation also took about **1200ms**:

```
/**
 * Extract a portion of an image as a Vector of uints.
 * 
 * @param   drawable
 * @param   rect
 * @return
 */
public static function getByteArray(drawable: DisplayObject, rect: Rectangle): ByteArray {
    var data: BitmapData = BitDiff.getBitmapData(drawable);
    var pixels: ByteArray = data.getPixels(rect);
    data.dispose();
    return pixels;
}


/**
 * Perform a binary diff between two streams of pixel data.
 * 
 * If `ignoreAlpha` is false then will not normalise the 
 * alpha to make sure the pixels are opaque.
 * 
 * @param   ba1
 * @param   ba2
 * @param   ignoreAlpha
 * @return
 */
public static function diffByteArrays(ba1: ByteArray,
                                      ba2: ByteArray,
                                      ignoreAlpha: Boolean): ByteArray {

    // Reset position to start of array.
    ba1.position = 0;
    ba2.position = 0;

    var larger: ByteArray = ba1;
    if (ba1.bytesAvailable < ba2.bytesAvailable) {
        larger = ba2;
    }

    var len: Number = Math.min(ba1.length / 4, ba2.length / 4),
        result: ByteArray = new ByteArray();

    // Assume same length.
    var resultPixel:uint;
    for (var i: uint = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // XOR.
        resultPixel = ba1.readUnsignedInt() ^ ba2.readUnsignedInt();
        if (ignoreAlpha) {
            // Force alpha of FF so we can see the result.
            resultPixel |= 0xFF000000;
        }

        result.writeUnsignedInt(resultPixel);
    }

    // Seek back to the start.
    result.position = 0;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Good grief. Thank you so much. This is FAR, FAR BEYOND what I asked for, and is probably the greatest and most thorough answer I have seen on stack overflow, ever.

I didn't expect anything like this. I'd have been perfectly happy with just a pointer to that wiki page. But instead, as well as giving me that resource, you've also done ALL the heavy lifting for me, AND mapped out a range of other possible approaches, AND taught me shedloads about writing readable, concise but complex shaders in the process.

Obviously, this is "the correct answer".

Comment: Even if I was the sound guy, I would not yell at you if you dropped the mic at the end of that post.

Comment: You're welcome, it was fun and something a bit different to try out - never underestimate the power of procrastination :P

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible options depending on what you want to achieve (e.g. is the XOR per channel or is it just any pixel that is non-black?).

1. There is the [BitmapData.compare() method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#compare()) which can give you a lot of information about the two bitmaps. You could [BitmapData.threshold()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#threshold()) the input data before comparing.
2. Another option would be to use the [draw method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw()) with the [BlendMode.DIFFERENCE blend mode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BlendMode.html#DIFFERENCE) to draw your two images into the same `BitmapData` instance. That will show you the difference between the two images (equivalent to the Difference blending mode in Photoshop).
3. If you need to check if any pixel is non-black then you can try running a [BitmapData.threshold](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#threshold()) first and then draw the result with the difference blend mode as above for the two images.

Are you doing this for image processing or something else like per-pixel hit detection?

To start with I'd have a look at [BitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) and see what is available to play with.

Comment: I'm guessing you're thinking of "black" as 0, and "anything else" as 1, and your idea of a XOR filter is "show something where either image has a non-black value".

Unfortunately, XOR filters are more complicated: bitwise, non-lossy and reversible. XOR an image with a key image twice, and you get back your original image. For example, basic image scrambling, or where drawing a shape onto an image that you might want to remove again.